# Let $f(x) =\ x^2-4x-3,\ x>2$ and $g(x)$ be the inverse of $f(x)$. Then the value of $\frac{1}{g'(2)}$ , where $f(x)=2$, is?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, polynomials

Let $f(x) =\ x^2-4x-3,\ x>2$ and $g(x)$ be the inverse of $f(x)$. Then the value of $\frac{1}{g'(2)}$ , where $f(x)=2$, is?
(here g' represents the first derivative of g)

$\\
\text{My working}\\
\begin{align}\\\text{f and g are inverse
}\\\therefore\  g.f&=1\ (Identity)\\
(g.f)(x)&=1\\
\text{differentiating...}\\
\\
(g'f)(x)+(g.f')(x)&=0\ .....(1)\\
\\
\text{Now since we are given to find when f(x)=2}\\
\\
\therefore\ x^2-4x-3&=2\\
\Rightarrow\ x^2-4x-5&=0\\
\Rightarrow\ x=5\ or\ x=-1\\
\text{But since x>2 (given condition), we reject x=(-1), hence x=5}\\
\\
\text{Now from above equation 1...}\\
\\
g'(2).f(2)+g(2).g'(2)&=0\\
\\
Also,\ f'(x)&=2x-4\\
\Rightarrow\ f'(2)&=0\\
\\
\Rightarrow\ g'(2).(-7)+g(2).(0)&=0\\
\Rightarrow\ g'(2)&=0\\
\text{Now, what I need is}\ \frac{1}{g'(2)}\ which\ is\ now\ \frac{1}{0}=\infty\\
\text{But the answer has to be an integral value}\\
\end{align}$

I am confused if I should have solved the equation 1 with x=5 instead of x=2 then once again with x=2 and solving those two equations but I think the need is for something else or the error is in the question where it should have been $\frac{1}{g'(5)}$ in place of $\frac{1}{g'(2)}$. Because if it was $\frac{1}{g'(5)}$ then solving f(x)=2 would have made some relevance. If I am making some error then please help and advise me. Give hints then I will try solving myself or if you're mentioning the answer then try spoiler tags. Thanks :)

Comment: It is the *functional inverse*, not the multiplicative inverse. You should be using the **chain** rule and not the product rule in the answer above.

Comment: $(f\circ g)(y)=y$ for all $y$, so by the chain rule, for every $y$, $(f\circ g)'(y)=1$, hence $f'(g(y))\cdot g'(y) = 1$. Hence, $g'(y) = \dfrac{1}{f'(g(y))}$. Now, plug in $y=2$. In particular, you will have to find what is $g(2)$, and plug that into $f'$

Comment: @Harshit Bhardwaj, use MathJax only for mathematical terms.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I too thought about that but how can I find g(2). I can make the subtitution $y=f(x)=x^2-4x-3$ and then find x in terms of y and substitute y as x and x as $f^-1(x)$. But how to do this in quadratic functions I can do it with linear functions easily but don't have any idea on quadratics. :(

Comment: Plug in $y=2$, and find what is $x$ (that is what $g(2)$ means). Also, when you solve the quadratic equation, you'll find two solutions, to decide which is the relevant one, look at the restrictions in the question. Edit: I just realized you did exactly this in your work. So, at this point I'm not sure what the issue is anymore (if you want to do it for a general $y$, just apply the quadratic formula: $x^2-4x-(3+y) = 0$, so $x=\frac{4 +\sqrt{4^2 -4(a)[-(3+y)]}}{2}$, where we choose the $+$ instead of $-$ because $x>2$)

Comment: @SarGe It was my first time today with MathJax and took me almost an hour I will keep it in mind next time.

Comment: (sorry the $a$ should be $1$; that's a typo)

Comment: The tag ([tag:functional-analysis]) is intended for questions about infinite dimensional vector spaces. This tag isn't relevant here. Please make sure to read a tag's description before using it for your post in the future

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the question, $g$ is the inverse of $f$, where $f$ is a real-valued function. And $f(x) = x^2 - 4x - 3 \quad$ for $x > 2$. And $f \in \mathscr{C}^{2} $

Now $$ f(x) = x^2 - 4x - 3 = 2 \implies x^2 - 4x - 5 = 0 \implies (x - 5) \cdot (x + 1) = 0 $$
Then, we have $x = 5$. and $f^{- 1}(2) = 5$, Therefore as the answer previously mentioned that $(5, 2)$ is the point on the curve we are concerned about.

Then,
\begin{align*}
&(g \circ f) (x) = I(x) = x\\
\implies  & g'(f(x)) \cdot f'(x) = 1 \quad \text{differentiating w.r.t. } x\\
\implies & f'(x) = \dfrac{1}{g'(f(x))} \quad ~\text{for those }x > 2 \text{ such that } g'(f(x)) \neq 0\\
\end{align*}
The rest of the argument is similar to the previous post and this is a just an explanatory post.

Here is the graph of $f'(x)$ and $f(x)$, subject to the constraint $x > 2.$

[image]

Comment: Ok now I get it why the question stated $\frac{1}{g'(2)}$ and at $f(x)=2$. This means that $f(x)=2$ at $x=5$ and I need to find $f'(5)$ and that is the required answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

$y=f(x)=x^2-4x-3 \implies f(5)=2 \implies f^{-1}(2)=5=y_0$
S0 $(2,5)$ is point$(x_0, y_0)$ which falls on the curve, then
$$\frac{1}{g'(2)}=\left(\frac{d}{dy}f^{-1}(y)|_{y=y_0=5}\right)^{-1}=f'(x_0)=0$$
One may note that if inverse $f^{-1}=g$ exists, then $$g'(y_0)=\frac{1}{f'(x_0)}$$

Comment: How is $\left(\frac{d}{dy}f^{-1}(y)|_{y=y_0=5}\right)^{-1}=f'(x_0)$? And how did we get $f^{-1}(5)$

Comment: Please see the edit,